# ng build gives an error because of regExp

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-aot

i have regExp in constants:

```
export const Constants = {
    QUERY_PARAM_CONFIG: {
        REGEX: /\+/gi,
        REGEX_ENCODED: /%2B/g
    }
};
```

but when i run ng build i get an error:

```
ERROR in app\app.module.ts(58,21): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Expression form not supported in 'Constants'
    'Constants' contains the error at app\configuration\constants.ts.
```

npm build script:

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing none --sourcemaps=true
```

any ideas?

Comment: probably the problem is in the way how you use it - not the way you define it. Post a code from your AppModule. Also post exact command you are executing (e.g. `ng build` vs. `ng build --prod`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The regex literals are not supported by AOT. See the [list of supported syntax](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#expression-syntax).

In order to make it work transform your regex to something supported e.g. string:

```
const before = /\+/gi, // before, could be the same as below

const after = { re: '\\+', flags: 'gi' }
const canBeUsedAs = new RegExp(after.re, after.flags);
```

By this you can still pass the meaning of the RegExp and create one on the fly whenever you need them in the runtime

Comment: I have the same issue using the text-mask library. 
I need to provide an array of regex like [/\d/, /\d/, '.',/\d/] but if I use 
[
      new RegExp('\\d/'),
      new RegExp('\\d/'),
      '.',
      new RegExp('\\d/')
]

It doesn't work...:(

Comment: I have the same issue     /translate3d\(\s?(?<x>[-]?\d*)px,\s?(?<y>[-]?\d*)px,\s?(?<z>[-]?\d*)px\)/   Could you help me on this ?